# if condition in where clause of sql query

Tags: sql-server

Below is my where clause of the query when i want data for a specific user

```
where Completion_Date>= '11/01/2011' 
and Completion_Date<= '12/11/2012' 
and System_user_id = 1234
```

and below is the where clause when i want to pull data for all the user:

```
where Completion_Date>= '11/01/2011' 
and Completion_Date<= '12/11/2012'
```

Since i dont want 2 seperate queries, is there a way to add a condition in where clause so that i can use a single query and depending on the input (i.e System_user_id) it will decide on whether to add extra condtion in the query.
I will be sending -1 when i want data for all users & for a specific user its system_user_id will be sent.

Comment: I have updated the answer with results and a reference from SQLFiddle, please do take a look. :) If you need I can still keep the earlier version of the answer though.. ;)

Comment: You said you didn't want 2 separate queries in the question but then mark the answer with two separate queries as the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may try the following procedure.

**Updated Query**

```
declare @userid int = -1
if (@userid = -1)
    BEGIN

     SELECT * FROM mytable 
     where Completion_Date>= '11/01/2011' 
     and Completion_Date<= '12/11/2012' 
     and userid in 
         (select distinct userID from mytable)
    end
ELSE
    BEGIN

     SELECT * FROM mytable 
     where Completion_Date>= '11/01/2011' 
     and Completion_Date<= '12/11/2012' 
     and userid = @userid 

end;
```

Results:

```
USERID  NAME    COMPLETION_DATE
123     john    2011-11-01
125     tim     2011-11-02
127     ron     2011-11-08
```

- REference [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63ed0/2)

**To see a specific user:**

- Reference [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63ed0/1)

---

## **ANOTHER METHOD**

Updated after latest comment from OP

- [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91e84/1)

Query:

```
DECLARE @uid int = -1
SELECT 
*
FROM mytable 
WHERE 
( CASE 
     WHEN @uid <> -1 THEN @uid
     ELSE userid
  END
) = userid

and Completion_Date>= '11/01/2011' 
     and Completion_Date<= '12/11/2012' 
;
```

Results: when @uid = -1

```
USERID  NAME    COMPLETION_DATE
123     john    2011-11-01
125     tim     2011-11-02
127     ron     2011-11-08
```

Please comment if you have tried this out :)

Comment: @avinashchavan can you run without then ;)

Comment: @Diamond Geezer i had to settle with that answer as i googled alot but didnt find a suitable answer.Also, a DBA friend of mine suggested me the same approach.
If you have a better way of doing it, then please let me know.

Comment: @avinashchavan I have updated to give you another shorter method. Try that out as well please :).

Comment: And I am voting up @Diamond Geezer for his answer since it too is correct :)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
WHERE ((@System_user_id = -1)
  AND (Completion_Date >= '11/01/2011') 
  AND (Completion_Date <= '12/11/2012'))
OR ((@System_user_id <> -1) 
  AND (System_user_id = @System_user_id) 
  AND (Completion_Date >= '11/01/2011') 
  AND (Completion_Date <= '12/11/2012'))
```

A variation on this using a Common Table Expression ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b759/24/0))

```
;WITH CompletionDates AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Completion_Date >= '11/01/2011'
    AND Completion_Date <= '12/11/2012'
)
SELECT * 
FROM CompletionDates
WHERE (@System_user_id = -1) OR (System_user_id = @System_user_id)
```

Comment: @bonCodigo Thank you. Generally I would code using IF blocks (like in your answer) because the intention is clearer. Doing "IF" statements in the WHERE clause can become difficult to read and debug if there are numerous optional parameters.