# How to use "is not null" as an input of variable in sql procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a procedure that will filter with a certain date or null date like :

> settledate = '2014-03-05'
>
> settledate is not null
>
> settledate is null

My question is how to make a variable like @settledate to accept any one of these three input?

```
create procedure sp_transaction_details

@ticker nvarchar(7),

@account nvarchar(3),

@settledate nvarchar(20)

as

select TrxDate AS [Date], 

case buysell when 'b' then Lot end AS [BuyingQty],

......

from Transaksi where Ticker = @ticker and AID = @account AND SettleDate = @settledate
;
```

I need 3 options because I want to know :

A transaction with a certain date

Transactions that have been settled

Transactions that have not settled yet

Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found an answer from the link below and adjusted to suit my case :

[if condition in where clause of sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858239/if-condition-in-where-clause-of-sql-query)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_transaction_details @ticker nvarchar(7),
                                               @account nvarchar(3),
                                               @options int, @settledate nvarchar(10) = NULL AS if(@settledate IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
SELECT TrxDate AS [Date],
       CASE buysell
           WHEN 'b' THEN Lot
       END AS [BuyingQty],
       ......


FROM Transaksi
WHERE Ticker = @ticker
  AND AID = @account
  AND SettleDate = @settledate END ELSE if(@options = 1) BEGIN
  SELECT TrxDate AS [Date],
         CASE buysell
             WHEN 'b' THEN Lot
         END AS [BuyingQty],
         ......


  FROM Transaksi WHERE Ticker = @ticker
  AND AID = @account
  AND SettleDate IS NULL END ELSE if(@options = 2) BEGIN
  SELECT TrxDate AS [Date],
         CASE buysell
             WHEN 'b' THEN Lot
         END AS [BuyingQty],
         ......


  FROM Transaksi WHERE Ticker = @ticker
  AND AID = @account
  AND SettleDate IS NOT NULL END ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you need correctly - define your date parameter as

```
@settledate nvarchar(20) = null,
```

This way, when calling the SP if there's no date to pass - you can omit the parameter from the call completely (by the way if it's a date indeed - declare it as `Date` or `DateTime` instead).

Then define your condition as

```
AND (@settledate IS NULL OR SettleDate = @settledate)
```

this means: if no date is passed - return all dates. If date is passed - use it as a filter

Comment: It works, thanks. But how about the third option "IS NOT NULL"?

Comment: @xpw but then what would be the difference between specific date passed and any "not null" date passed? Still the date will be used as a filter?

Comment: May be my question is not clear, so I edited my question where I have mentioned what I need.

Comment: I found an answer from stackoverflow.com/questions/13858239/…, thanks for Yuriy's answer, it is one of the possible answers.