# SQL - Adding conditions to SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, gaps-and-islands

I have a table which has a timestamp and inCycle status of a machine.  I'm using two CTE's and doing an INNER JOIN on row number so I can easily compare the timestamp of one row to the next.  I have the DATEDIFF working and now I need to look at the inCycle status.  Basically, if the inCycleThis and  inCycleNext both = 1, I need to add it to an InCycle total.

Similarly (Shown table will make this clear):

```
incycleThis/next = 0,1 = not in cycle
incycleThis/next = 0,0 = not in cycle
incycleThis/next = 1,1 = in cycle
```

If I was doing this client side, this would be pretty simple.  I need to do this in a stored procedure though due to there being a lot of records.  I'd love to use an 'IF' in the SELECT section, but it seems that's not how it works.

The result I'm looking for at the end is simply:  `InCycle = Xtime`.  Something like:

```
SUM(Diff_seconds if((InCycleThis = 1 AND InCycleNext = 1) OR (InCycleThis = 1 AND InCycleNext = 0))
```

This is what I have so far:

```
WITH History_CTE (DT, MID, FRO, IC, RowNum)
AS
(
SELECT DateAndTime
    ,MachineID
    ,FeedRateOverride
    ,InCycle
    ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY MachineID, DateAndTime) AS "row number"
FROM History
WHERE DateAndTime >= '2020-11-15'
    AND DateAndTime < '2020-11-16'
),

History2_CTE (DT2, MID2, FRO2, IC2, RowNum2)
AS
(
SELECT DateAndTime
    ,MachineID
    ,FeedRateOverride
    ,InCycle
    ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY MachineID, DateAndTime) AS "row number"
FROM History
WHERE DateAndTime >= '2020-11-15'
    AND DateAndTime < '2020-11-16'
)
SELECT DT as 'TimeStamp'
,DT2 as 'TimeStamp Next Row'
,MID
,FRO
,IC as 'InCycle this'
,IC2 as 'InCycle next'
,RowNum
,DATEDIFF(s, History2_CTE.DT2, History_CTE.DT) AS 'Diff_seconds'
FROM History_CTE
INNER JOIN
    History2_CTE ON History_CTE.RowNum = History2_CTE.RowNum2 + 1
```

[image: result when run]

Comment: Try to use CASE condition in WHERE. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858239/if-condition-in-where-clause-of-sql-query

Comment: Please post desired results. If using `SUM`, what are the groups you want to aggregate by?

Comment: Thanks for the link Mihal, I think I can make CASE work if I know how to make the reference to the result.  I'm thinking I would add a new SELECT SUM('Diff_seconds') AS 'EarnedValue' FROM History_CTE - but it doesn't like that.  How do I refer to the previous result?

Comment: @Parfait - looking to sum Diff_seconds from rows where InCyleThis = 1 AND InCycleNext = 1 OR InCycleThis = 1 AND InCyleNext = 0

Comment: Unless I missed something, your first two CTEs are exactly the same. You don't need two of them - just self-join History_CTE to itself. And do you really gain anything by using  `DATEDIFF(s,` rather than `DATEDIFF(second,`? Which is more readable?

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding a third CTE to first conditionally calculate your needed value. Then aggregate for final statement. Recall CTEs can reference previously defined CTEs. Be sure to always quailfy columns with table aliases in `JOIN` queries.

```sql
WITH 
    ... first two ctes...
, sub AS (
  SELECT  h1.DT AS 'TimeStamp'
        , h2.DT2 AS 'TimeStamp Next Row'
        , h1.MID
        , h1.FRO
        , h1.IC AS 'InCycle this'
        , h2.IC2 AS 'InCycle next'
        , h1.RowNum
        , DATEDIFF(s, h2.DT2, h1.DT) AS 'Diff_seconds'
        , CASE 
             WHEN (h1.IC = 1 AND h2.IC2 = 1) OR (h1.IC= 1 AND h2.IC2 = 0)
             THEN DATEDIFF(s, h2.DT2, h1.DT) 
          END AS 'IC_Diff_seconds'
  FROM History_CTE h1
  INNER JOIN History2_CTE h2
     ON h1.RowNum = h2.RowNum2 + 1
)

SELECT SUM([Diff_seconds]) AS Diff_seconds_Total
     , SUM([IC_Diff_seconds]) AS IC_Diff_seconds_Total
FROM sub
```

And if needing to add groupings, incorporate `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT h1.MID
     , h1.FRO
     , SUM([Diff_seconds]) AS Diff_seconds_Total
     , SUM([IC_Diff_seconds]) AS IC_Diff_seconds_Total
FROM sub
GROUP BY h1.MID
       , h1.FRO
```

Even aggregate calculations by day:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(date, [TimeStamp]) AS [Day]
     , SUM([Diff_seconds]) AS Diff_seconds_Total
     , SUM([IC_Diff_seconds]) AS IC_Diff_seconds_Total
FROM sub
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, [TimeStamp])
```

Comment: Wow, that is exactly the direction I was headed working on it.  Hopefully I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

> The result I'm looking for at the end is simply:  `InCycle = Xtime`.  Something like:
>
> ```
> SUM(Diff_seconds if((InCycleThis = 1 AND InCycleNext = 1) OR (InCycleThis = 1 AND InCycleNext = 0))
> ```

As I understand your question, you just need to sum the difference betwen the timestamp of "in cycle" rows and the timestamp of the next row.

```
select machineid, 
    sum(datediff(s, dateandtime, lead_dateandtime)) as total_in_time
from (
    select h.*, 
        lead(dateandtime) over(partition by machineid order by dateandtime) as lead_dateandtime
    from history h
) h
where inclycle = 1
group by machineid
```

Comment: I like where you're going with this, its simple.  When I correct the capitalization SQL still doesn't like "lead" at the beginning of line 5.  Why is that because it still seems to run.  Also, I get the 3 CTE thing to work and it runs faster than this more simple method (yes, I added in my parameters so its pulling the same number of record)

Comment: @BrianTremelling: I would be surprised if the multiple CTE solution performs better. The logic of the two queries is quite similar, but the above uses built-in window functions only rather than multiple self-joins.